# How to reduce or not send rtcp rr packets when silent

Tags: webrtc

When muted, I found that the sending frequency of rtcp rr packets is too high. I want to reduce the sending frequency or even not send them. What modifications do I need or where do I need to modify the source code

Comment: Are you running WebRTC between browsers, or are you using a specific WebRTC library?

Comment: i am running webrtc on android, and use source code  then combile it.